# Why am I getting TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str' with pandas' cut() function?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm receiving `TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'` while using pandas' cut() function. More specifically, the usage is

```
spending_bins = [0, 585, 630, 645, 680]
labels = ["<$585", "$585-630", "$630-645", "$645-680"]
school_spending_df = per_school_summary.copy()
school_spending_df["Spending Ranges (Per Student)"] = pd.cut(school_spending_df["Per Student Budget"], bins=spending_bins, labels=labels)
```

`school_spending_df.head()` looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FMhmT.png).

But exactly which strings and integers are being compared and clashing here?

I can't think of what to try, other than leaving off the labels since it's an optional argument, which has not effect, nor did setting the arguments `right` and `include_lowest`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try converting dtype of `Per Student Budget` column into float:

```
school_spending_df["Spending Ranges (Per Student)"] = pd.cut(school_spending_df["Per Student Budget"].str[1:].astype(float), bins=spending_bins, labels=labels)
```